# How do I reach the first GPS cache I see?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

In *Tomb Raider*, just after you reach the first campsite, there is a GPS cache on a small rock jutting out from the rocky wall.

I've tried jumping to this ledge, from every angle I can think of, to no avail. I *know* there's something up there. It glows yellow in my Survival Instincts. I just can't get to it.

**How do I reach this GPS cache?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is the one I am thinking of you need to walk past it, down the hill towards the shed.

Turn right at the shed then bear to your right again you will see a ledge that you can climb and come up behind the ledge in question.

Comment: I... feel so dumb now.